# Convert multi-line text file with lists to hashtable in Common Lisp

Tags: list, file-io, common-lisp, hashtable

Say that I have a text file which is formatted like this:

```
(:question
 (hello
  how
  are
  you))

(:answer
 (i
  am
  fine
  thanks))
```

which I wish to read and then convert into a hashtable where the first words (starting with a :) are the keys, and then the inner lists are the values for the given keys. How can I do this? I have tried several approaches to this problem, but I cannot find a good way to read the file and then convert it to a hashtable.

Comment: If you've tried several approaches, please expose the one(s) you're more confident about as a proof of prior effort, and as a starting point.

Comment: It would be easier if you used a plist directly instead of almost one. then you could just use `#'read` and `#'alexandria:plist-hash-table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you posted [an attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981908/1281433), it might be worth comparing how it could be done a little bit more simply.  The **loop** macro supports a bunch of different clauses, and some can be very handy here.  If I knew that I could read values of the form (key value) from a stream until there were no more values (in this case, until either a **nil** is read, or the end of stream is encountered), I'd do something like this:

```
(defun read-hashtable (&optional (stream *standard-input*))
  (loop
     with table = (make-hash-table)         ; the hash table
     with sentinel = (cons 1 1)             ; unique value for EOF
     for x = (read stream nil sentinel nil) ; read value, sentinel if EOF
     until (eq sentinel x)                  ; until EOF, indicated by sentinel
     do (setf (gethash (first x) table) (second x)) ; set a value in the table
     finally (return table)))                       ; finally return the table
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
(with-open-file (in ".../input.txt")
  (read-hashtable in))
;=> #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 2 {10056B2C43}>
```

If you're averse to **loop**, it's easy to do this with **do**, as well:

```
(defun read-hashtable (&optional (stream *standard-input*))
  (do* ((sentinel (cons 1 1))
        (table (make-hash-table))
        (x (read stream nil sentinel nil) (read stream nil sentinel nil)))
       ((eq x sentinel) table)
    (setf (gethash (first x) table) (second x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem using the following code:

```
(defun symbols-to-lowercase-strings (sym-list)
  (let ((newlist (list '())))
    (loop for symbol in sym-list
       do (progn
        (setf symbol (string symbol))
        (setf symbol (string-downcase symbol))
        (push symbol newlist)))
    (subseq newlist 0 (- (length newlist) 1))))

(defun read-file (filename)
  (let ((classes (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
    (class-lists NIL))
    (with-open-file (stream filename :direction :input)
      (loop
     for line = (read stream nil)
     while line
     collect line
     do (push (cons (car line) (cdr line)) class-lists))
      (loop for line in class-lists
     do (setf (gethash (car line) classes) (list (symbols-to-lowercase-strings (car (cdr line))) '(0)))))
    classes))
```